# Magento Import configurable product in magento by Dataprofiler Magento Default

Tags: php, magento

I want to import configurable product in magento by Dataprofiler Magento Default.

Here its my CSV but only configurable is create not associated product.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czoAT.png)
I know that third party tool like Magmi and other...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, DataFlow import tool does not support import of associated simple products to configurable products out of the box, so you need to use *System > Import/Export > Import* or extension.